# VBA - Excel. Change query connection via button and promptwindow

Tags: vba, excel, connection

I have a query linked to a textfile (with extension .eqp)
I placed a button next to my pivottable, which should open a promptwindow, and change the connection's location to the new selected *.eqp file. All other query-settings should stay the same.

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
Dim Ret

    Ret = Application.GetOpenFilename("EQP Files (*.eqp), *.eqp")

    If Ret <> False Then
        Sheets("CalculationSheet").QueryTables(1).Connection = "TEXT;" & Ret
    End If
    ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
End Sub
```

I put the refreshAll in there too, since I saw no change happen when I just replaced the connections location. Can anyone explain me what goes wrong? the prompt shows up, the refresh happens, but the query is just empty. nothing there.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you'll need ret.selecteditems(1)

Comment: "object required" error.. :/

Comment: try selecteditems.count it might be (0)

Comment: I'm pretty new to all vba.. What are you trying to accomplish by using that count? what should happen?

Comment: it should count the selected items, so you should have 1.   Do a bit of reading on how to debug VBA, it will help, a lot of questions can be answered by using Locals/Immediate and Watches.